# Supervisord - ini file error on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, supervisord

I installed Supervisor on CentOS 6.5 and currently experiencing some weird error that I can't seem to fix.

I created a `supervisord.conf` file in `/etc` directory and call supervisor like this:

```
$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Which looks pretty basic. But this error keeps appearing:

```
Error: .ini file does not include supervisord section
```

My supervisord.conf file looks like:

```
[program:supervisord]
command=/usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.out.log
```

Does anybody know what's the problem here?

Comment: Do you *also* have a `[supervisord]` section?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I don't seem to know this stuff very well.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html). The program section above is right, but you also need the other section I mentioned in the same file as it contains all the global settings.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're probably missing the `[supervisord]` section in the file. See [this](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-settings).

For [example](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-example),

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel = info
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = false
minfds = 1024
minprocs = 200
umask = 022
user = chrism
identifier = supervisor
directory = /tmp
nocleanup = true
childlogdir = /tmp
strip_ansi = false
environment = KEY1="value1",KEY2="value2"
```

Comment: Is there any particularly important options I need to specify for the [supervisord] section? I currently leave it blank.

Comment: All the options are optional and are mostly related to logging, so nothing too important unless you need them.

Comment: this doesn't fix the problem for me

Comment: You should check if your supervisord is using correct configuration file. Also empty `[supervisord]` block is enough because none of its fields is required.